# Crear Schedule en Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Me gustaría crear un Schedule para mi Job en Oracle, pero a la hora de indicar la fecha de inicio y final de mi Schedule aparece el error:

```
ORA-27418: error de sintaxis en el intervalo de repetición o el calendario
```

Este es mi Schedule:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE (
        schedule_name   =>  'SCHEDULE_LOG_FREE_SPACE_TABLESPACE',
        start_date      =>  TO_DATE('01/01/2021','DD/MM/YYYY'),
        repeat_interval =>  'FREQ=DAILY; BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT,SUN; BYHOUR=23:59',
        end_date        =>  TO_DATE('31/12/21','DD/MM/YYYY'),
        comments        =>  'Every day at 23:59');
END;
```

Quiero que mi Job se ejecute todos los días a las 23:59 desde el 01/01/2021 hasta el 31/12/31. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?